# Images do not show up on Facebook in my wordpress directory, but work in other directories

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

Help! Up until a week ago images from my website worked fine when I would post to Facebook. Now, nothing shows up. I have OG tags set up in my header that work beautifully, it's just that the image shows up blank. Ex: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmydigitalmind.com%2Fblog%2F2013%2F03%2Flast-summers-barred-owls%2F

Notice the image area is blank? If you click on the image, you will see the image, but it still shows blank on Facebook.

I've narrowed the issue down a bit, but I need help solving it. My Wordpress is set up in a directory on my server /wp/ - the site itself redirects to the root using the exact method that Wordpress recommends.

If I load an image from any other directory on my website, it will load up just fine on Facebook. An example is here: http://mydigitalmind.com/IMG_5902.jpg - if you paste that image in your status, it shows up.

Take that same image an put it in my /wp/ directory: http://mydigitalmind.com/wp/IMG_5902.jpg and now it does not show up on Facebook.

Comment: Have you checked `.htaccess`? Besides, most sides prevents hotlinking and blocks such referrerings

Comment: I wonder if it's the redirect? It's just odd that it suddenly doesn't want to work when nothing has changed between last week and this week. My .htaccess only has what Wordpress put in it.

Comment: Pablo, you put me on the right track! Some plugin must have changed my htaccess that was in my WP directory. It added this:



RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^facebookexternalhit
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ogtags.php?$1 [L,QSA]

So I removed that and it WORKS now. THANK YOU for putting me on the right track. Sometimes you just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Would you mind if I post this as an answer to accept and close this question?

Comment: Pablo - that is fine with me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your `.htaccess` file - in most cases it's the reason that prevents image hotlinking (most websitaes got such solution to avoid excessive traffic).